# Can one provide a simple search and replace script for me please?

Tags: shell, replace

Is ist possible to make a (Perl or whatever running on Mac OS X) script that converts

```
\section{long text}
\sectionmark{short text}
```

to

```
\section[long text]{long text\sectionmark{short text}}
```

or alternative to

```
\section{long text}[short text]
```

I can’t ensure that there are no line breaks in the `long text` or if there is a break between `\section` and `\sectionmark`.

This question is related with a problem discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42981/how-to-set-rightmark-after-section-command/43047#43047) an TeX.SX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '/\\section{long text}/ { oldline=$0
                              getline
                              gsub("{","[",oldline)
                              gsub("}","]",oldline) 
                              print gensub("(.*)\\[(.*)\\]","\\1[\\2]{\\2","g",oldline) $0 "}"
                              getline
                            }
     1' INPUTFILE
```

Will do it for you if there are no line breaks in `long text` and there is no empty line between `\section` and `\sectionmark`. If you have any of those, you can still modify it.

So to answer your question: yes it is possible.

**UPDATE**

Here is a working solution, with `awk`:

```
awk '/\\section{/ { oldline=$0
                    if ( oldline ~ /}/ ) {
                        lt=gensub(".*{([^}]+)}.*","\\1","g",oldline)
                    } else {
                        lt=gensub(".*{(.*)","\\1","g",oldline) 
                        getline tmp
                        while ( tmp !~  "}" ) {
                            lt=lt "\n" tmp
                            getline tmp
                        }
                        lt=lt "\n" gensub("}.*","","g",tmp)
                    }
                    getline
                    while ( $0 !~ /\\sectionmark/ ) {
                        getline
                    }
                    printf("\\section[%s]{%s%s}\n",lt,lt,$0)
                    getline
                  }
     ! /\\section{/ { print }' INPUT_FILE
```

**Note**: it does not handle if anything appears between `long text}` and `\sectionmark` e.g.:

```
\section{long text}**THIS TEXT WILL BE SKIPPED!!**
\sectionmark{short text}
```

You can see it in [ACTION HERE](http://ideone.com/KDlAY)!

If you want to get rid of then new lines in `long text` just replace every `"\n"` with a `" "` in the script.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you pleas tell me how to modify if there are line breaks inside of `long text`, cause there are some …

Comment: Well it depends. My paypall address is my name at gmail.com. ... ok it was a lame joke, but you should put some effort in it... anyway I'm updating my answer sometimes later...

Comment: Thank you again, that saves me  a lot of handicraft and time. “put some effort” normally I do this and don’T ask questions without doing some research my self and expecting that someone provides the full code but this time I didn’t know where to start searching since I never scripted something and furthermore the deadline comes closer and closer O:-) Are there any resources you can recommend on questions/tasks/script like this one?

Comment: For general scripting with `bash` I'd recommend: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html and for general text processing: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html (`sed` is a good tool too, but awk can do most of its job).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "\section{long text\nwith\nsome\nlinefeeds}\n\sectionmark{short text\nwith\nsome\nlinefeeds}" | 
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\(\\section{[^}]*}\)[\s\n]*\\sectionmark{\([^}]*\)}/\1[\2]/g'
\section{long text
with
some
linefeeds}[short text
with
some
linefeeds]
```